# Alignment Issues with fixed-background images

Tags: html, css

Not exactly sure how to phrase the question in the first place here but I'll give it a go.

I have an image that I want to fixed-scroll down the page, which I want to change colour smoothly as it enters a second div with a different coloured background. I've got the divs sorted, the images placed perfectly and the effect I want working excellently - my only problem now is that I cannot align the two images for the life of me, due to using percentages etc.

I have a working example here you'll certainly need to look at - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtJBn/61/) - you may need to resize the page around a little bit to understand the particular alignment issue I'm having. The top "Hello" sits a set amount off-center, which I want to achieve with the second "Hello". I just can't get it to happen! Any suggestions? I've been looking at possible jQuery solutions but no luck so far.

Thanks heaps for any answers. Cheers.

Comment: Your to "hello" element is positioned with a combination of percentage & pixel measurements. Unfortunately, that can't be done on a background image - yet. `calc` will help us out eventually.

Comment: Yeah, I'd figure that was going to be an issue. Surely there is a way around somehow though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: have you tried background-position: left center;

Comment: Yeah I have, the issue is that there will be text below the "Hello" in the second section. Having it sit at left center makes things look a little ugly when the copy gets put in so I'd rather not have to place it there. It also doesn't work well with my other margins. If there is simply no other way though this would work, for sure, I'd just have to change my layout a whole bunch. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Seems I found a solution, though I wouldn't call it ideal. It works well though! After Chad said to try `background-position: left center;` I realized if I simply put the image as **`background-position: center;`** and made the image have a bunch of blank space to one side, with enough twiddling on photoshop I'd manage to line the two up. Works great now, lines up perfectly in all my browsers.

Here's the example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtJBn/100/) (though you cant see much of a change in it, as it's the image itself that had to be altered.)

Thanks for the replies guys.

Answer (score 1):

**Live demo link here**  http://jsfiddle.net/EtJBn/107/

Hi now you can do easily this

Just define some properties as like this

**Css**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#top{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#bottom{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:200;
}

#topsq {
    position:fixed;
    height:175px;
    background:url("http://mattwaymouth.com/images/hello_small.png") no-repeat center top;
    left:0;
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;


}    

#second {
    position:relative;
    background: url("http://mattwaymouth.com/images/hello_small_green.png")  no-repeat center 50px fixed;         
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 200;
        height:300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="topsq"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/EtJBn/107/